# Fiware - how to connect PEP proxy to Orion and configure both with HTTPS?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wilma

I am working with Orion and I try to protect the future apps using the PEP proxy and Keyrock, but I cannot find  a way combine these 3 GE. All my base files are in [this repository](https://github.com/RiosQ/IFiware), although I have running  Orion, Keyrock and Cygnus, I cannbot send requests using the PEP proxy.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"
networks:
  fiware:
    driver: bridge
services:
# Base de datos Orion
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4.7
    hostname: mongodb
    container_name: mongodb
    expose:
      - "27017"
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    command: --smallfiles
    networks:
      - fiware
# GE encargado de la publicación y suscripción
  orion:
    image: fiware/orion:latest
    hostname: orion
    container_name: orion
    links: 
      - mongodb
    expose:
      - "1026"
    ports:
      - "1026:1026"
    volumes:
      - "./data/db/mongo:/data/db:rw" 
    command: -dbhost mongodb
    networks:
      - fiware
# GE encargada de la persistencia de datos
  cygnus:
    image: fiware/cygnus-ngsi:latest
    hostname: cygnus
    container_name: cygnus
    volumes:
      - "./config/cygnus/agent.conf:/opt/apache-flume/conf/agent.conf:rw"
      - "./config/cygnus/grouping_rules.conf:/opt/apache-flume/conf/grouping_rules.conf:rw"
    links:
      - mysql-cygnus
    expose:
      - "5050"
      - "8081"
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - CYGNUS_MYSQL_HOST=mysql-cygnus
      - CYGNUS_MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - CYGNUS_MYSQL_USER=root
      - CYGNUS_MYSQL_PASS=fiware
      - CYGNUS_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
    networks:
      - fiware
# Base de datos para historicos
  mysql-cygnus:
    image: mysql
    hostname: mysql-cygnus
    container_name: mysql-cygnus 
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=fiware
    volumes:
      - "./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
    networks:
      - fiware
# GE de control de acceso 
  authzforce:
     image: fiware/authzforce-ce-server:release-5.4.1
     hostname: authzforce
     container_name: authzforce
     expose:
         - "8080" 
     ports: 
         - "8080:8080"
# GE encargado de la administración de seguridad
  keyrock:
    image: fiware/idm:latest
    hostname: keyrock
    container_name: keyrock
    volumes:
        - "./config/idm/keystone.db:/keystone/keystone.db:rw"
        - "./config/idm/local_settings.py:/horizon/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py:rw"
        - "./config/idm/keystone.conf:/keystone/etc/keystone.conf:rw"
    links:
        - orion
    expose:  
        - "5000"
        - "8000"
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
        - "8000:8000"
    networks:
        - fiware
# GE encargado del redireccionamiento
  pepwilma:
    image: ging/fiware-pep-proxy
    hostname: pepwilma
    container_name: pepwilma
    volumes:
        - "./config/pepproxy/config.js:/opt/fiware-pep-proxy/config.js:rw"
    links:
        - keyrock
        - orion
        - authzforce
    volumes_from:
        - keyrock
    expose:
        - "80"
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    networks:
- fiware
```

Creating and getting the token as you can see in the next wiki: [get token](https://github.com/RiosQ/IFiware/wiki/04.-Integraci%C3%B3n-de-IDM-con-Ori%C3%B3n).

As you can see here: [token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRSUk.png).

I cannot continue because PEP proxy shows an error when I make the request to: [postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBm2N.png) (without specifying a port).

using this config.js: [config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HJiG.png).

got this error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n401n.png).

```
ERROR: Server - Caught exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token E
```

someone have a suggestion, and someone knows how can I deploy the https support?

thanks for all...

Comment: Your main doubt is related to PEP setup, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is: "Auth-token not found in request header". This means that you are not passing an auth-token in the headers of your request.

To solve your problem, you need to get a valid token this way:

```
POST to "http://idm_ip:8000/oauth2/token"  
Payload: grant_type=password&username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD&cli ent_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
Headers: 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Basic AUTH_HEADER'
```

Change "idm_ip" and all "YOUR_..." to your correct values. AUTH_HEADER must be changed to a Base64 encode of this information: “client_id:client_secret” - something like `base64(client_id + “:” + client_secret)`.

With the received token, you can do your GET/POST request informing the headers as follow:

```
Headers: 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Token': 'your received IdM token'
```

You can find more information in this [tutorial about Orion, Keyrock and Wilma integration](https://pt.slideshare.net/daltoncezane/integrating-fiware-orion-keyrock-and-wilma).

Comment: as you can see here:   [github issue](https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/issues/92)

i already got the token and the error persist, i follow that tutorial many times and in the last step i got the error.

do you have other suggestion?

Comment: Dalton, i got this error: 

`pepwilma        | 2018-03-27 12:51:15.556  - INFO: Root - Access-token OK. Redirecting to app...
pepwilma        | Refused to set unsafe header "accept-encoding"
`

Comment: By your github messages, it seems you fixed the error... The `domain` error you are getting is from `authzforce`, since you did not create some access policy... If you do not need to work with `authzforce` just set `enabled: false` at PEP `config.js` file. I hope the answer and the comments have helped you.

Comment: yes Dalton, for any reason, when the authzforce container was present in the docker-compose file, disable it was not an option then i only coment that part.